# adding owner into SQL Server 2005 database

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

SharePoint on SBS Server 2008 has been playing up lately and just gives a 404 message. I think I have found what is wrong with it. The database seems to have no owner![No database owners][1]

I am trying to resolve this at the moment using

```
USE SampleDB
EXEC sp_changedbowner 'DOMAINNAME\USERNAME'
```

command. This gives me an error:

> Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Could not locate entry in
>   sysdatabases for database 'SharePoint_AdminContent_d4e397f2'. No entry
>   found with that name. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Does anyone know how to apply an owner to the database?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is with the `USE SampleDB` command.  The error indicates that it can't find your `SharePoint_AdminContent_d4e397f2` database.  Check the spelling of your database in the `USE` command.